# Set up Hadoop KMS

Tags: hadoop, key, tde

I tried to set up Hadoop KMS server and client.

below is my kms.site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>hadoop.kms.key.provider.uri</name>
   <value>jceks://file@/${user.home}/kms.keystore</value>
   <description>
      URI of the backing KeyProvider for the KMS.
   </description>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hadoop.security.keystore.java-keystore-provider.password-file</name>
   <value>kms.keystore.password</value>
   <description>
     If using the JavaKeyStoreProvider, the file name for the keystore password.
   </description>
</property>
```

In core-site.xml added below

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri</name>
    <value>kms://http@mydomain:16000/kms</value>
</property>
```

in hdfs-site added below

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri</name>
    <value>kms://http@mydomain:16000/kms</value>
</property>
```

Then restarted hadoop and used ./kms.sh start to start kms

But when i m trying to generate a key using below command

```
hadoop key create key_demo -size 256
```

i m getting below message , am i missing anything ?

```
There are no valid (non-transient) providers configured.
No action has been taken. Use the -provider option to specify
a provider. If you want to use a transient provider then you
MUST use the -provider argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using hadoop 3.3.1

this is my `kms-site.xml`:

```
<property> 
    <name>hadoop.kms.key.provider.uri</name> 
    <value>jceks://file@/${user.home}/kms.keystore</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
    <name>hadoop.security.keystore.java-keystore-provider.password-file</name> 
    <value>kms.keystore.password</value> 
</property>
```

this is my `core-site.xml`:

```
<property> 
    <name>hadoop.security.key.provider.path</name>
    <value>kms://http@localhost:9600/kms</value>
    <description> 
        The KeyProvider to use when interacting with encryption keys used 
        when reading and writing to an encryption zone. 
    </description> 
</property>
```

Before adding those to my core-site.xml, I also get the same message as yours. I think you are using hadoop v2, so your port number for keyProvider are still 16000, I use v3. I also see that you are still using JavaKeyStoreProvider like the example in hadoop documentation (so am I), if you don't provide "password file" which is `kms.keystore.password` the KMS will terminate immediately after starting up. So, you would need to place an empty file in your classpath, which is in `/hadoop_home/etc/`

I know i arrive quite late, hope it help.